# Как сделать выборку записей за текущий год в mysql

Tags: mysql, выборка

Есть уже готовый вложенный запрос, как дописать к нему, чтобы выборка еще была за текущий год?

```sql
SELECT * FROM applycant
WHERE casenum = (SELECT casenum FROM prosedures WHERE proseduresname = 'Статус беженца' OR 'Временное убежище' ) 
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: а где в вашей таблице хранится год и в каком виде?

Comment: хранится в applycant, столбец createdate, формат ('YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добавить условие для выборки только за текущий год, можно использовать функцию `YEAR()` для извлечения года из даты и сравнить его с текущим годом, который можно получить с помощью функции `YEAR(CURDATE())`:

```
SELECT * FROM applycant
WHERE casenum = (SELECT casenum FROM prosedures WHERE proseduresname IN ('Статус беженца', 'Временное убежище')) 
AND YEAR(date_column) = YEAR(CURDATE())
ORDER BY id;
```